# Print comma separated values from list in same <p> in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I want to print values from a list comma seperated in same p tag. I have tried something like this

```
{% for item in list %}
    <p>{{item}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But this print values on different lines
 
item1,
item2

I want everything to be printed in one line i.e item1, item2 
I guess because p tag is within for loop so each time new p tag gets generated. Is there a way to read through list and not generate different p tag and print items in same p tag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the `<p>` tags outside the for loop. You can also use `<span>` to inline the items:

```
<p>
{% for item in list %}
<span>{{item}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}</span>
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

Comment: Note, this solution renders the comma with an extra space after each item, i.e. `A , B , C`, vs the expected `A, B, C`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print a list with comma separated, just use `join` in jinja.

```
<p>{{ list | join(", ") }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This provided me with the correct, expected spacing while allowing for looping over models, not just scalar types

```
{% for item in list %}
    {{ item + ',' if not loop.last else item}}
{% endfor %}
```

And if item was an model, i.e. object, with some text field "name"....

```
{% for item in list %}
    {{ item.name + ',' if not loop.last else item.name}}
{% endfor %}
```